# Как писать в CSV файл табличные данные, с возможностью по ним построить график?

Tags: xls

Здравствуйте!
В СSV  файл записываю время и высоту.

```
 using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\11.csv", true, Encoding.Default))
                {

                    if (height[i] != 55555)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(GetTime() + ";" + height[i]);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
```

По этим данным нужно построить график. Как можно это сделать, чтобы при открытии файла - график уже был построен?

Пытаюсь создать график, пока с пустыми данными. Но при сохранении выдает - что это уже не формат "СSV -разделители-запятые"

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить создать xls-файл с двумя листами - сам график и таблица, значения в которой будут извлекаться из csv-файла.

Comment: а как извлечь данные из csv файла в таблицу  xsl  файла?

Comment: просто в  csv  данные пишутся в цикле, по таймеру записывается новая запись, а нужно чтобы когда закончился цикл - открывался excel  с графиком из высоты и времени..

Comment: могу скинуть пример, укажите на какой мэйл.

Comment: anya.udalova.92@mail.ru
буду благодарна за помощь)